# GWT: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call for com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseListLoadResult

Tags: java, glassfish-3, gwt-rpc, application-server, gxt

I have a SerializationException in RPC call.
GWT version is: 2.4.0.
Extjs.gxt lib version is: gxt-2.3.1-gwt22.
If i deploy my app in tomcat 7 it works, bu in glassfish - no.
Help me, please.
Server is **Glassfish v3**.

```
Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseListLoadResult' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BaseListLoadResult@5dc57a
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:130)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:587)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:471)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:563)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:211)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:251)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

my classes:

```
public interface UnitServiceAsync {
    void findAll(AsyncCallback<ListLoadResult<OrgUnitDTO>> callback);
}

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("Unit")
public interface UnitService extends RemoteService {

    ListLoadResult<OrgUnitDTO> findAll();
}

public class PersistenceService extends RemoteServiceServlet {
    ...
}
```

and its implementation:

```
public class UnitServiceImpl extends PersistenceService implements UnitService {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1433248587426826168L;

    @Override
    public ListLoadResult<OrgUnitDTO> findAll() {
        ...
        List<OrgUnitDTO> subList = new ArrayList<OrgUnitDTO>(); 
        ...
        return new BaseListLoadResult<OrgUnitDTO>(subList);
    }
}

public class OrgUnitDTO extends BaseModel implements IsSerializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2392916533158255302L;

    //getters
    //setters

    public OrgUnitDTO() {}
}
```

I went through a lot of solutions, like a:
class should implement Serializable or IsSerrializable interfaces, should gave a default constructor and so on.
The most interesting thing is that on tomcat it is works fine for me, but on glassfish - this exception.
I do not know what to do, help me, please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
In WEB-INF/lib folder was a jetty libs. when i removed this libs - all worked fine.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same problems, but in my case only in the devmode. All RPC rules placed in generated "rpc" folder, you should check that it's available and actual on your sever. Also the problem threw from the server you can simply debug it, the problem should be somewhere GWT takes rpc policies and matche them on your request.

P.S.
In my experience, the best way to avoid those situations is don't use GXT classes as dto objects, especially GXT 2 classes.

Comment: could you tell me more about "rpc" folder? what is the folder and where it placed?